# Default ActiveRecord Associations in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm trying to implement a persitent model Setting storage in Rails, using the Active Record. I've already saw other gems like [ledermann/rails-settings](http://github.com/ledermann/rails-settings), but I don't want other dependency, because I'll use it only for one model and need the ability to customize it.

I've created 3 models, "**Company**", "**Setting**", "**CompanySetting**". For the association, I done the follow:

**company.rb**

```
has_many :company_settings
```

**setting.rb**

```
has_many :company_settings
has_many :company, through: :company_settings
```

**company_setting.rb**

```
belongs_to :company
belongs_to :setting
```

But I've a problem, for example, I seed the Settings table with N settings, and I need to have these Settings built when I try to access the Company settings, since they don't have an **CompanySetting** entry for that Setting.

My attempt was the follow:

**company.rb**

```
has_many :company_settings
accepts_nested_attributes_for :company_settings
def load_company_settings
  Setting.all.collect { |setting|
    company_settings.find_by( setting: setting ) || company_settings.build( { setting: setting, value: '' } )
  }
end
```

And then, in **my form** (using Simple Form):

```
= f.simple_fields_for :company_settings, @company.load_company_settings do |s|
  = s.input :value
```

It renders the correctly number of fields (the N fields in my Setting table), and return they values if exist, otherwise, returns an empty string as value. But when I do a POST, it doesn't saves.

I believe that I'm doing the right thing in Rails 4 Strong Params, so, my **companies_controller** look like that:

```
class Company::CompaniesController < Company::BaseController
  def show
    @company = current_company
  end

  def edit
    @company = current_company
  end

  def update
    @company = current_company
    if @company.update(company_params)
      redirect_to company_path
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private
    def company_params
      params.require(:company).permit(:name, company_settings_attributes: [:id, :value, :setting])
    end
end
```

Table Structure - Company:

- id

Table Structure - Setting:

- title (value to show to user)
- key (value used in application)

Table Structure - CompanySetting:

- company_id
- setting_id
- value

Thanks (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed that, with these steps:

.1 Customize the Model adding the methods for return the list of all possible settings from Setting model, and build new ones with CompanySetting. You need to create an assign method in the class, because when the Strong Params try to save, it will try to find this method.

```
def settings
    Setting.all.collect { |setting|
      company_settings.find_by( setting: setting ) || company_settings.build( { setting: setting, value: '' } )
    }
  end
  def set_setting(key, value)
    company_settings.find_or_create_by( setting: Setting.find_by(key: key) ).update(value: value)
  end
  def settings=(attributes)
    attributes.map { |key, value| 
      set_setting(key, value)
    }
  end
```

asd

.2 Update the Form to use this new method (Here I added two types of fields, booleans and not booleans. This is based on `is_boolean` property in Setting

```
= f.simple_fields_for :settings do |s|
            - for setting in @company.settings
              .form-group
                - if setting.setting.is_boolean
                  .checkbox
                    %label
                      = s.input_field setting.setting.key.to_sym, as: :boolean, boolean_style: :inline, checked: setting.value == "1"
                      = setting.setting.title
                    %span.help-block= setting.setting.description
                - else
                  = s.label setting.setting.key.to_sym, setting.setting.title, class: 'control-label'
                  = s.input_field setting.setting.key.to_sym, class: 'form-control', value: setting.value
                  %span.help-block= setting.setting.description
```

.3 Fix your Strong Params

```
def company_params
      params.require(:company).permit(:name,
        settings: [
          :setting_key_1,
          :setting_key_2,
          ...,
          :my_other_n_setting
        ]
      )
    end
```

Done.